# Change Apache MPM from prefork to worker

Tags: php, apache, configuration, debian

I need to change MPM prefork module to worker but it's not working on my Debian 9.1. When I enable worker module, PHP is not working. I can't enable php7.0 module back.

Here is the output from console:

***root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # apachectl -V | grep -i mpm***

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2a01:4f8:171:fc2::2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Server MPM:     prefork

***root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # a2enmod mpm_worker***

Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_worker:
Considering conflict mpm_prefork for mpm_worker:
ERROR: Module mpm_prefork is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!

***root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # a2dismod mpm_prefork***

ERROR: The following modules depend on mpm_prefork and need to be disabled first: php7.0
root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # a2dismod php7.0
Module php7.0 disabled.

To activate the new configuration, you need to run:

systemctl restart apache2

***root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # a2dismod php7.0***

Module php7.0 disabled.

To activate the new configuration, you need to run:

systemctl restart apache2

***root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # a2enmod mpm_worker***

Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_worker:

Considering conflict mpm_prefork for mpm_worker:

Enabling module mpm_worker.

To activate the new configuration, you need to run:

systemctl restart apache2

***root@Debian-91-stretch-64-LAMP ~ # a2enmod php7.0***

Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.0:

Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:

Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:

ERROR: Module mpm_worker is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!

ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php7.0, aborting

Comment: The conflict tells you that you cannot have both mpm's enabled: event _and_ worker. And that you cannot use the internal php module with the worker mpm.

Comment: You want to use the worker mpm along with the php-fpm factcgi process manager. That works, I actually switched one of my systems to exactly that setup today ;-)

Comment: So what I have to do?

Comment: Well, disable the event mpm, install and configure php-fpm, that includes an additional php configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I got the following error

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2 
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.2:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Module mpm_event is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php7.2, aborting
```

And to fix I simply did

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

you might also want to try restarting your server