# I am getting "Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:" when enabling php7.0

Tags: php, apache

When running "a2enmod php7.0", I am getting the below error. Is this just ignorable or an issue ?. How do i resolve this ?

```
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.0:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:
Module php7.0 already enabled
```

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258053/change-apache-mpm-from-prefork-to-worker